# I'm trying to mock Generating an Email token using Identity in .net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-core

I'm trying to do some Mocking in .Net core specifically around Identity.
I have created a .Net core class library project and I'm confident I have all the correct references. The first thing I am trying to Mock is the Identity method GenerateConfirmationTokenAsync method as I'm trying to Mock setting up of registered users. 
Here's what I have so far in my test class I'm using moq and Xunit.

```
public class ServiceTests
{
    private readonly string _email;
    private readonly string _subject;
    private readonly string _message;
    private readonly Mock<IAccountService> _accountService;
    private readonly ApplicationUser _applicationUser;
    private readonly Mock<VisualJobsDbContext> _identityDbContext;

    public ServiceTests()
    {
        _email = "me@gmail.com";
        _subject = "test from me";
        _message = "hello I got to you";
        _accountService = new Mock<IAccountService>();
        _applicationUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = _email, Email = _email };
        _identityDbContext = new Mock<VisualJobsDbContext>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GenerateConfirmationToken()
    {
        Mock<DbSet<ApplicationUser>> userMock = DbSetMock.Create(_applicationUser);

        var register = await _accountService.Object.Register(userMock.Object.First(), "password");

        var token = await _accountService.Object.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userMock.Object.First());

        Assert.NotNull(token);
    }
```

my ApplicationUser  class inherits IdentityUser 'register' and 'token' are always null. if I look on userMock I cant see  a token either.

Comment: This is of course not going to work, you have not set up your mocks to do anything. Also from your setup its not really clear which class you want to test. `VisualJobsDbContext`? Its the only concrete class I can see

Comment: @Tseng `VisualJobsDBContext` is from my repository layer. Using Identity to Generate the token a user has to be registered first, so I'm trying to set up a valid user object `ApplicationUser` that inherits from `IdentityUser` since `IdentityUser` is the class that Identity Expects. Once I have created an ApplicationUser Object I pass that to the Identity method for creating the token, but it seems not to work

Comment: `IdentityUser` is just a poco model, containing data. You don't need to mock it, just create an instance of it. See my answer below, with a hypothetical service that generates the token (Since I don't know the implementation or dependencies of your services). With mock you test behavior, which you can't test with Test Driven Design. You can use TDD to test output, but to test behavior you need mock. Mocks basically are proxy classes around other classes or interfaces (commonly interfaces) which return a fixed value for your test which is difficult to do otherwise

Comment: @bilpor, what is the target system/class/method under test? In your question you generate mocks and assert the mocks. Common practice is to mock dependencies of the system under test  in order to be able to test it (the SUT) in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test a mock you first need to set it up to do something, otherwise it's just an empty interface with no implementation.

In your specific case its seems like you don't need a mock at all. You create an instance of `ApplicationUser` user, create a DbSet mock from it and then take the first object out of it. It's the same as directly passing the `ApplicationUser` instance to your service.

Instead, that you are passing the `ApplicationUser` to the mock, which has no implementation at all, so you are not testing anything at all actually.

```
public class ServiceTests
{
    private readonly string _email;
    private readonly string _subject;
    private readonly string _message;
    private readonly Mock<IAccountService> _accountService;
    private readonly ApplicationUser _applicationUser;
    private readonly Mock<VisualJobsDbContext> _identityDbContext;

    public ServiceTests()
    {
        _email = "me@gmail.com";
        _subject = "test from me";
        _message = "hello I got to you";
        _applicationUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = _email, Email = _email };
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GenerateConfirmationToken()
    {
        // Does it have dependencies? If yes, you may need to mock them
        var _accountService = new AccountService(.../*mocked dependencies*/);
        var register = await _accountService.Register(_applicationUser, "password");

        var token = await _accountService.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userMock.Object.First());

        Assert.NotNull(token);
    }
```

Now, it depends what kind of logic you have inside `Register` and `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` and which dependencies you have in your `AccountService` if you need moq or not.

Let's assume you have a service called `TokenGenerator` which implements `ITokenGenerator` interface.

```
public class ServiceTests
{
    private readonly string _email;
    private readonly string _subject;
    private readonly string _message;
    private readonly ApplicationUser _applicationUser;
    private readonly Mock<ITokenGenerator> _tokenGenerator;

    public ServiceTests()
    {
        _email = "me@gmail.com";
        _subject = "test from me";
        _message = "hello I got to you";
        _applicationUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = _email, Email = _email };
        _tokenGenerator = Mock<ITokenGenerator>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GenerateConfirmationToken()
    {
        // #### Setup ####
        // Reads: If GenerateToken method is called with the **exact** same instance as the user passed to the service
        _tokenGenerator.Setup(t => t.GenerateToken(It.Is(user)))
            // then return "abc123456" as token
            .Returns("abcd123456")
            // Verify that the method is called with the exact conditions from above, otherwise fail
            // i.e. if GenerateToken is called with a different instance of user, test will fail
            .Verifiable("ContainsKey not called.");

        // #### ACT ####

        // Pass the token generator mock to our account service
        var _accountService = new AccountService(_tokenGenerator.Object);
        var register = await _accountService.Register(_applicationUser, "password");
        var token = await _accountService.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userMock.Object.First());

        // #### VERIFY ####
        // Verify that GenerateToken method has been called with correct parameters
        _tokenGenerator.Verify();
        // verify that the GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync returned the expected token abc123456
        Assert.Equals(token, "abcd123456");
    }
```

Example which verifies that `UserManager<T>.CreateAsync` is called:

```
        // #### SETUP ####
        var _userManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
            .Setup(um => um.CreateAsync(It.Is(user))
            .Verifiable("UserManager.CreateAsync wasn't called!");
        var _accountService = new AccountService(_userManager);

        // #### ACT ####
        var register = await _accountService.Register(_applicationUser, "password");

        // #### VERIFY ####
        // Verify that GenerateToken method has been called with correct parameters
        _userManager.Verify();
        // verify that the GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync returned the expected token abc123456
```

This ensures that your `AccountServce.CreateAsync` Methods does a call to Identity. In case you later add logic, this will ensure that also in future the call is made or test will fail if you add some logic which prevents `CreateAsync` from being called. This test tests the behavior.

**Edit**

As a side note in case you don't know how mocks work: The original code of `UserManager<T>.CreateAsync` will **NEVER** be executed. The mock completely overrides this method (hence it only works with interfaces and classes with `virtual` methods!!) and skipping its whole logic and just returns a predefined value (one you specify in the `.Returns(...)` method during setup of the mock).

Mockups are there to return fake/predetermined values, so you have deterministic way to test a class or functionality. In integration tests, the mock is of a lower value than in unit test where you only want to test a specific piece of code (a unit), without external dependencies like database, filesystem or networking

Comment: HI @Tseng. the methods in _accountService are just wrappers for the Identity objects : So taking the Register method for example calls `_userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser,password)` where _userManager has been declared as `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: Then there is no need to test the `Register` method, unless you want to test that it really calls `_userManager.CreateAsync` with the given parameters and also there is no need to test `UserManager<T>` because its already been tested by Microsoft (github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/test). You only need to test **your application's logic**. I'll extend my example above to show you an example on how you can test your Register method that i really calls the user manager. If you need integration tests, you can use EntityFramework's InMemory package for an in memory database

Comment: Hi @Tseng, the reason I'm trying to moq is because at the moment I dont have a mail sever, but I want to ensure that I have my security mechanisms working as expected. Through IDentity I have extended the default user and I have changed the default PK type of string to int. For registering a user is first to register the user this should create the basic user details in the db, we then generate a key based on the registration and this would be sent to the user for verification. I want to mock the applicationuser table being populated and a key generated. so I can test verified or not verified